# What happens if an input is applied to an output enabled pin of a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I have enabled a digital pin of microcontroller CC2650 as an output pin. Being curious about the circuit, I placed a push button with one end to this pin and other end to the +5V pin.  Interestingly whenever I push the switch, the microcontroller boots up again.

So my question --- What happens if an input is applied to an output enabled pin of a microcontroller?

Comment: You tell it: the microcontroller is booting up... ;)

Comment: i know its booting up but why

Comment: There is [no "why" in your question above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Just a "what happens". Anyway, @tcrosley gave you a proper answer and you accepted it. You can upvote it, too, for extra appreciation.

Comment: @GeroldBroser accepted that there is no why oops sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop doing this -- you're creating a short.

Since the pin is configured as an output, but presumably the port bit is set at 0, this is the same as ground (or very nearly ground).  So this is essentially the same as short +5 to ground -- except in this case the short is going through the output pin's CMOS transistor.  Not good.

This is temporarily dropping the supply voltage to the microcontroller, which is causing it to reboot.  Keep this up, and you will probably burn out the chip (it will overheat).

(edit, from my comment) The processor reboots because the short between the output pin and +5 shorts the power supply, causing the power supply to drop below the minimum supply voltage necessary to keep the processor running. As soon as this happens, the short is removed because the pin is no longer configured as an output. So the power supply recovers momentarily, and the processor starts back up again. But if the switch is still held down, this will just repeat as soon as the code runs that sets the pin as an output.

Even if the output was configured high before you set it as an output, then you would still have a partial short because the voltage of an output pin is usually not quite equal to the supply voltage.  So you would still be sinking some current.

The only case where you wouldn't have a short is if the pin is set high, and the pin is configured as an open-drain output.  In this case, the pin is normally driven high externally, but always through a resistor, and not a direct connection to the supply voltage

Comment: Thank u sir @tcrosley but why does this temporarily drop the supply voltage to the microcontroller is it because it finds an additional source other than the power supply

Comment: @virajitviru The keyword is ["short \[circuit\]"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit). U = I ⋅ R and if R tends to 0...

Comment: So it gets short means device fails and immediately it finds the original power supply and boots up back Thanks for the time @tcrosley

Comment: @virajitviru Not exactly. "get short", per se, means "wiring a short circuit". The device fails due to voltage level drop due to R → 0 due to short circuit. The "original" power supply is always there. Lucky you that it apparently isn't strong enough to keep the voltage level when the current increases according to I = U / R with R → 0. If it were: higher current means more heat, much higher current (theoretically → ∞ if R = 0) means much more heat, much more heat means IC death.

Comment: @virajitviru It doesn't "find" the original power supply, that was always connected.  The processor reboots because the short between the output pin and +5 shorts the power supply, causing the power supply to drop below the minimum supply voltage necessary to keep the processor running.  As soon as this happens, the short is removed because the pin is no longer configured as an output.  So the power supply recovers momentarily, and the processor starts back up again.  But if the switch is still held down, this will just repeat as soon as the code runs that sets the pin as an output.

Comment: @tcrosley it explains good but when i was thinking back again on it what will be the path for the short is what which is now bothering me we know the generic block diagram of a port i couldnt find the path for a short

Comment: @virajitviru A output pin usually has two CMOS transistors in a totem-pole configuration; the top one connected to VCC and the bottom one to ground.  In your case, the bottom one is enabled connecting the output pin to ground.

Comment: @tcrosley the same question i was asking to my colleague he expresses in this way that the concept of the short is wrong and he denies it an his explaination was as follows

Comment: The tristate buffer for the output is enabled and so the pull up and pull down resistors are disabled now when i applied the voltage across this output enabled pin it was finding a path to drive into the pin as it cant be driven into the output buffer  it would now find its way into the input buffer and an interrupt is being generated and the microcontroller boots up

Comment: But a serious question was without enabling the input buffer it would be in high impedence state how can current be driven into it                                                                                               @tcrosley sir do u think this explaination sounds meaningful ????

Comment: @virajitviru In your original post you said you enabled the pin as an an output.  I have given you an explanation, more than once now, than fully explains why connecting that pin to the power rail creates a short and causes the processor to reboot.  Others seem to agree with my analysis or I wouldn't have upvotes.  You're trying to over-think this.

Comment: @tcrosley I find u r answer to be more appropriate but the other answer does it mean any sense to u is what I am asking sir

Comment: @virajitviru no it does not.

Comment: @virajitviru What do you mean by "the other answer"? There is just this one here. Or was there one which has been retracted?

Comment: @GeroldBroser he was referring to his three comments starting with "the same question I was asking to my colleague..."